# How to find the value of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{1}^{e}(\ln x)^n\ dx$

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

In my textbook, the following relation is defined $I_n=\int_{1}^{e} (\ln x)^n\ dx$. The first part of the exercise asks me to find a recurrence relationship, which I did:

$$I_n = (n-1)(I_{n-2}-I_{n-1})$$

Then, as the title says, I need to find $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{1}^{e}(\ln x)^n \ dx$$ I know the value is $0$, but I am stuck at actually solving it. So far, I tried to find two other formulas whose limits are $0$ and squeeze mine between them, but this idea didn't help me much. I'm thinking that I could use the recurrence I found, but do now know how exactly.

Comment: Try iterating the recurrence backwards, all of the way down to something you can find easily, e.g. $n=1$, or solving it via another means of your preference. It'll be messy, but doable, and it should, I believe, telescope in a manageable way.

Comment: The limit is $0$ by DCT (Domianted Convergence Theorem).

Comment: **[Long Comment]** I wanted to expand upon my comment on the recurrence relation and got stuck making use of it. Making note of this here for anyone who may be able to make use of it. First: Observe that the recurrence may be written as 

$$I_n = (n-1) I_{n-2} - n I_{n-1} + I_{n-1}$$

Hence, rearranging, we get the identity
$$
I_n + n I_{n-1} 
=   I_{n-1} + (n-1) I_{n-2}
$$
We can actually back-iterate this on itself repeatedly, in a sense, owing to its self-similar nature. (This is in fact an argument I saw in the past, e.g. [this MSE post](https://is.gd/TSS81h).)

[cont.]

Comment: $$\begin{align*}
I_n + n I_{n-1} 
&=   I_{n-1} + (n-1) I_{n-2}   \\
&=   I_{n-2} + (n-2) I_{n-3}   \\ 
&= \cdots \\
&= I_2 + 2 I_1
\end{align*}$$

Of course, $I_1,I_2$ are finite constants, and this sum can be shown to be $e$. Hence,

$$I_n = e - n I_{n-1} \tag{$\ast$} $$

Why bother? This recurrence is significantly easier to handle:

$$\begin{align*}
I_n
&= e - n I_{n-1} \\
&= e - n \Big[ e - (n-1) I_{n-2} \Big] \\
&= (1-n)e + (n-1) I_{n-2}   \\
&= (1-n)e + (n-1) \Big[ e - (n-2) I_{n-3} \Big]   \\
&= -  (n-1)  (n-2) I_{n-3} \\
&= \cdots
\end{align*}$$

[cont.]

Comment: **[Why am I stuck?]** This ends up seeming to run into factorial-like behavior, skipping a few factors and only at multiples of $3$ subtracted from the index ([Wolfram agrees](https://is.gd/Y9lfCl)), but nonetheless this would be at odds with use of it in the limit since $I_1 > 0$ for instance (so the limit as $n \to \infty$ would *seemingly* blow up), but there's obviously something missing. But the recurrence $(\ast)$ certainly seems to work, even working upwards from $I_1$, so where's the issue? Maybe it's just something I'm overlooking by being tired.

Comment: @PrincessEev, yes it is $n(n-1)I_{n-2}$ and not $(n-1)I_{n-2} $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put $y=\ln x$. The integral becomes $\int_0^{1} y^{n}e^{y}dy$. Now use the fact that $e^{y} \leq e$ and evaluate $\int_0^{1}y^{n}dy$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\ln x \leq 1+\frac{x-e}e$ on $[1,e]$ hence we have$$0\leq I_n\leq\int_1^e\left(1+\frac{x-e}e\right)^ndx=\frac{e-e^{-n}}{1+n}$$

Answer (score 2):

For $0<\delta<e-1$, write
$$
\int_{1}^{e}(\ln x)^n \ dx=\int_{1}^{e-\delta}(\ln x)^n \ dx+\int_{e-\delta}^{e}(\ln x)^n \ dx=:A_n(\delta)+B_n(\delta)
$$
and observe that $0\leqslant A_n(\delta)\leqslant \int_1^{e-\delta}(\ln(e-\delta))^ndx=(e-\delta-1)\left(\ln(e-\delta)\right)^n$ and $B_n(\delta)<\delta$.